Proving a simple consequence of the Compactness Theorem
I am self-learning logic, and trying to prove the following exercise using the Compactness Theorem:

Suppose $T$ is a theory for language $L$, and $\sigma$ is a sentence of $L$ such that $T \models \sigma$ ($\sigma$ is a consequence of $T$).  Prove that there is some finite model $T' \subseteq T$ such that $T' \models \sigma$.

I get the sense that this should be easy to prove, but I am not coming up with a satisfying argument.
The argument I want to make is: $T \models \sigma$ iff $T \cup \{\neg \sigma\}$ is unsatisfiable, implying no $T' \cup \{\neg \sigma\}$ is satisfiable, where $T'\subseteq T$ is finite.  From here I want to then derive the conclusion but am not sure how.
Alternatively, recalling that since $T \models \sigma$ means, by definition, for model $U$, if we have $U \models T$, then $U \models \sigma$.  Would it then be wrong to argue that, if $T \models \sigma$, then $T \cup \{\sigma\}$ is satisfiable, and hence every finite subset of $T \cup \{\sigma\}$ is satisfiable by the Compactness Theorem, and hence we have a finite $T'\subseteq T$ such that $T' \models \sigma$?

"finite model" is incorrect. Are you sure the exercise doesn't say "finite subtheory" or "finite subset"?
There are a number of basic logical errors in your two arguments (correctly using quantifiers, negating statements, etc). I'll give you feedback on what you wrote, which hopefully will lead directly to a solution.

$T \models \sigma$ iff $T \cup \{\neg \sigma\}$ is unsatisfiable, implying no $T' \cup \{\neg \sigma\}$ is satisfiable, where $T'\subseteq T$ is finite.

No, $T\cup \{\lnot \sigma\}$ unsatisfiable does not imply $T' \cup \{\neg \sigma\}$ unsatisfiable for all finite $T'$. For example, suppose $T = \{\sigma\}$, $\lnot \sigma$ is satisfiable, and $T' = \varnothing\subseteq T$. Then $T\cup \{\lnot \sigma\}$ is unsatisfiable, but $T'\cup \{\lnot \sigma\}$ is satisfiable.
What $T\cup \{\lnot\sigma\}$ unsatisfiable does imply (by the compactness theorem!) is that there is some finite $T'\subseteq T$ such that $T'\cup \{\lnot\sigma\}$ is unsatisfiable.

if $T \models \sigma$, then $T \cup \{\sigma\}$ is satisfiable, and hence every finite subset of $T \cup \{\sigma\}$ is satisfiable by the Compactness Theorem, and hence we have a finite $T'\subseteq T$ such that $T' \models \sigma$?

(1) $T\models \sigma$ does not imply $T\cup \{\sigma\}$ is satisfiable, unless you already know that $T$ is satisfiable. $T\models \sigma$ means that every model of $T$ satisfies $\sigma$, but how do you know there are any models of $T$ in the first place?
(2) The implication from "$T\cup \{\sigma\}$ is satisfiable" to "every finite subset of $T \cup \{\sigma\}$ is satisfiable" is obvious and does not require the compactness theorem.
(3) $T'\cup \{\sigma\}$ is satisfiable does not imply $T'\models \sigma$. $T'\cup \{\sigma\}$ is satisfiable if there is some model of $T'$ which satisfies $\sigma$. $T'\models \sigma$ if every model of $T'$ satisfies $\sigma$.

Thanks! Yes I misread the problem it was asking if there is a "finite sub theory" $T'$, not a finite model.  In your fourth paragraph, is why is it the case that $T\cup {\neg \sigma}$ unsatisfiable implies there is some finite $T' \subseteq T$ s.t. $T' \cup {\sigma}$ is unsatisfiable?  Specifically why $T'\cup {\sigma}$ unsatisfiable and not $T'\cup {\neg\sigma}$?

@user918212 That was a typo. I'll fix it now.

Thanks! I am embarrassed that I need to be lead on like this, but given that we know there is some finite $T' \subseteq T$ such that $T' \cup {\neg \sigma}$ is unsatisfiable, how do we conclude the existence of a finite $T' \models \sigma$?  I get the sense there is some basic detail I am still missing here.

@user918212  Write down the definitions of "$T'\models \sigma$" and of "$T'\cup{\neg\sigma}$ is unsatisfiable." Then think about them until it becomes clear that they say exactly the same thing. (It might be helpful to think what counterxamples would have to look like.)

@AndreasBlass I see now, thank you!
